# Config Files not copied to Test Agent when run Test Manager

Tags: c#, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I've a unit test project in VS2013 with a config file

[image: Solution Explorer]

I made a build in TFS with my testing project. I configure controller on TFS and agent on controller, create machine on Lab center.
But when try to run test on Test Manager I got this error:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: No se puede abrir el archivo configSource 'Configurations\Environment.config'. (C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTAgent\19426\TIPS151.tipsalud.local\Deployment\AutomationDRG.DLL.config line 13)

When I go to the folder, it doesn't contain the config file nor the configuration folder.

I didn't find any solution. Any idea??

Comment: It seems your issue is not TFS related, you just use a TFS build output, correct?

Comment: Yes, the build was generated correctly, including the files that i need. The problem appear when i execute my tests on Test Manager.

Comment: I found a solution but it isn't the best. I deploy the files manually from Microsoft Test Manager. I created Test Setting that deploy a folder with the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set **Copy to Output Directory** for *Environment.config* to **Cope always**.

[image]

Comment: File Environment.config was set in "Copy Always" but it doesn't appear in the Deploy folder

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it isn't the best. I deploy the files manually from Microsoft Test Manager. I created Test Setting that deploy a folder with the config file.

[Test Manager print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsmLb.png)